# Azure add external node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine

I have a managed Kubernetes cluster set up using the Azure Kubernetes service.

There is an external computer that I would like to use with this cluster. Is it possible to add a node which is external to the Azure Kubernetes service to the cluster?

Comment: likely this won't be allowed in PaaS platform, as you have taken a managed service, the master is also being managed by AKS service here

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you cannot add the external nodes to the AKS cluster, it's a managed service. You only can make other resources such as VM to connect to it. AKS only support to scale up to increase the nodes by the resource itself. And if you want to have all the control of the Kubernetes cluster, I recommend you use the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine), then you can add the external nodes and configure them yourself.